# Spring batch (spring boot - java config) multithreaded jdbc writer

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jdbc, spring-batch

I need to write a huge amount of data into mysql.

I want to do it in several threads or performance. I would like to use spring batch partitioning but never done this before.

My spring batch java config (part):

```
@Bean
ItemWriter<Event> writer() throws SQLException {
    return new CustomJdbcBatchDataWriter();
}

@Bean
public TaskExecutor taskExecutor(){
    SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor asyncTaskExecutor=new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor("spring_batch");
    asyncTaskExecutor.setConcurrencyLimit(threadsAmount);
    return asyncTaskExecutor;
}

@Bean
public Job importUserJob(JobCompletionNotificationListener listener) throws Exception {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("importUserJob")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .listener(listener)
            .flow(step1())
            .end()
            .build();
}

@Bean
public Step step1() throws Exception {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
            .<Event, Event>chunk(chunkSize)
            .reader(reader())
            .processor(processor())
            .writer(writer())
            .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
            .build();
}
```

And my custom jdbc writer (had to write it to disable autocommit - for performance):

public class CustomJdbcBatchDataWriter implements ItemWriter {

```
@Override
public void write(List<? extends Event> items) throws Exception {
try (
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/batch?useSSL=false&useServerPrepStmts=false&rewriteBatchedStatements=true",
            "user", "password") ) {
    connection.setAutoCommit(false);


    String sql = "INSERT INTO events VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

    for (Event p : items) {
        try {
            ps.setString(1, p.getId());
       //Setting rest of data into prepared statement
       ...
            ps.addBatch();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    ps.executeBatch();
    connection.commit();
}
}
```

}

How can I configure this so it will insert different data in different threads to gain performance?
Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: I don't think multithreading is the solution since you are io bound and not compute bound

Comment: But what if I need to put let's say 100 millions of records? I am going to insert 10 millions in one thread, then 10 millions in another, and so on.

Comment: Again that won't speed it up, 10 threads mean that the cpu is doing 10 things at once, what you need is a disk to do 10 things at once

Comment: But if now only one CPU core is utilized I believe multithreading could help. However this can be mistake. What would you recommend?

Comment: multithreading won't help cuz the bottle neck is the disk and network connection to the mysql database. The best way to speed things up would be to make the disk io faster such as by adding a sad

Comment: @SteelToe Adding threading will absolutely improve throughput. Spring Batch, while fast, is much slower to read/write from a file than most databases are at processing `insert`s. We've seen near linear performance improvements from increasing the number of threads in Spring Batch.

Comment: @DeanClark That is true. I tested inserts via plain jdbc and even in that case threading increases insert speed twice (even if I use only two threads). If I use more threads than two - there's some improvement also but not that huge as when going from single thread to two. Could you please help with partitioning for spring batch?

Comment: You don't need a custom jdbc writer, the spring one participates in the on going transaction and commits at the end of the chunk. You need to properly setup tx management, yours is also leaking connections so after x runs you are out of db connections.

Comment: @M.Deinum that is strange because I used standard jdbc batch writer and it was slow as it used autocommit. Transactions? Can you please give more details? Thank you.

Comment: You need a `DataSourceTransactionManager` and wire that into your step to make your chunks transactional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something to get you started. I haven't tested it, but it should at least get you close.

```
//updated this bean of yours. the others are new
@Bean
public Job importUserJob(JobCompletionNotificationListener listener) throws Exception {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("importUserJob")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .listener(listener)
            .flow(partitionStep())
            .end()
            .build();
}

@Bean
public Step partitionStep(){
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("partitionStep")
            .partitioner(step1()) //leverage the step you already have
            .partitioner("step1", partitioner())
            .gridSize(10) //# of threads
            .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
            .build();
}

@Bean
public Partitioner partitioner() {
    //Use this partitioner to add ranges for your reader
    //NOTE: your reader needs to be in @StepScope to pull from the Step Execution Context
    return new YourCustomPartitioner();
}

@Bean
public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
    return new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. And if I want writer to be partitioned then it should be in @StepScope too?

Comment: Yep. However, from what I can tell, your writer is thread-safe, so there might not be a need to do so. Side note: you may want to consider using `JdbcBatchItemWriter` instead of your custom one.